# Render Play 2.0 view programmatically

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

Using Play 2.1.0, I have a Java controller with an action responsible to render arbitrary html views.

For example:

```
class HtmlClientViews extends Controller {    
    public static void getView(String viewName) {
        return ok(/*How to render the view programmatically?*/)
    }
}
```

And in my views I have a view named account.html.scala.

I have a route like:

```
GET   /htmlclient/*viewName        controllers.HtmlClientViews.getView(viewName)
```

If I make a request like /htmlclient/account.html I want to render the view named account.html.scala

I haven't tried yet to use Java reflection mechanisms for this, but would like to know what is the most effective way to achieve this.

Comment: Is it possible to use a Map<String, Content> for this: account -> views.html.account() ?

Comment: I though about that also, but would have to maintain that map... Looking for a more maintainable solution, if exists

Comment: I don't know of any simple solution without reflection :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with:

1. reflections, like in `Play Authenticate` usage sample, there it's used for selecting different view depending on detected language
2. If you have known number of views you can use simple switch statement in controller to return view `a`,`b`,`c` or `d`.
3. Also as in case no. 2 - you can use `matching` statement in the view to include sub-view depending on some variable.

Comment: Will go with plain java reflection.